# Error: [UIPopoverBackgroundView setArrowOffset:] must be implemented by subclassers

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller, uipopoverbackgroundview

I follow this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29459668/uipopoverbackgroundview-contentviewinsets-must-be-implemented-by-subclassers) to implement a `UIPopoverBackgroundView`. I checked the `UIPopoverBackgroundView` class, I think I have implemented all required functions and variables, but the error still persist when running .

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIPopoverBackgroundView
>   setArrowOffset:] must be implemented by subclassers.'

```
import UIKit

class CustomPopoverBackground: UIPopoverBackgroundView {

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
    }

    override var arrowOffset: CGFloat {
        get {
            return 0.0
        }
        set {
            super.arrowOffset = newValue
        }

    }

    override var arrowDirection: UIPopoverArrowDirection {
        get {
            return UIPopoverArrowDirection.Up
        }
        set {
            super.arrowDirection = newValue
        }
    }

    override class func contentViewInsets() -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10)
    }

    override class func arrowBase() -> CGFloat {
        return 2.0
    }

    override class func arrowHeight() -> CGFloat {
        return 2.0
    }

}
```

Where did I wrong? What is `setArrowOffset`, I didn't find it in the class of `UIPopoverBackgroundView` or `UIPopoverBackgroundViewMethods` protocol.

Comment: You can't do `super.arrowOffset = newValue` in your `arrowOffset` setter.  The superclass setter throws that exception.

Comment: @dan Could you give an answer to show what should I do instead?

Answer (score 0):

Another blog [post](https://justanapplication.wordpress.com/category/ios/uikit/uipopoverbackgroundview/) that actually shows the implementation of custom `UIPopOverBackgroundView`

It holds the Arrow in a struct

```
private struct Arrow {
    let height    : CGFloat   = 30.0
    let base      : CGFloat   = 20.0

    var direction : Direction = .UP
    var offset    : CGFloat   = 0.0
}

override var arrowOffset: CGFloat {
    get {
        return arrow.offset
    }

    set {
        arrow.offset = newValue
    }
}
```

No super call here, the class expects subclass to actually hold the value and not use the superclass implementation.